# ObjectMapper how can I change datatype while Mapping in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data, objectmapper

I am using this [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library to map JSON to Core Data object and Vice versa.

But the problem here is I cant type cast objects.

here

```
import ObjectMapper
class network: NSManagedObject, Mappable {
  @NSManaged var localId: NSNumber?
  @NSManaged var version: String?
  @NSManaged var port: String?

  required public init?(map: Map) {
    let ctx = DbHelper .getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "network", in: ctx)
    super.init(entity: entity!, insertInto: ctx)

    mapping(map: map)
  }

   public func mapping(map: Map) {
    localId <- map["localId"]
    port <- map["port"] // Returns Int but I want to save it as String
    version <- map["version"] // Returns Int but I want to save it as String
  }
}
```

Here how to save version and port as String when I get value from JSON as Int.

Hope I am clear in explaining my question, if further clarification required please let me know.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

In a lot of situations you can use the built-in transform class `TransformOf` to quickly perform a desired transformation. `TransformOf` is initialized with two types and two closures. The types define what the transform is converting to and from and the closures perform the actual transformation.

For example, if you want to transform a JSON String value to an Int you could use `TransformOf` as follows:

```
let transform = TransformOf<Int, String>(fromJSON: { (value: String?) -> Int? in 
        // transform value from String? to Int?
        return Int(value!)
    }, toJSON: { (value: Int?) -> String? in
        // transform value from Int? to String?
        if let value = value {
            return String(value)
        }
        return nil
    })

id <- (map["port"], transform)
```

Here is a more condensed version of the above:

```
id <- (map["port"], TransformOf<Int, String>(fromJSON: { Int($0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map { String($0) } }))
```

I hope you can find solution from this.

Solution get from: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper

Comment: how can I do same for Int to String?

Comment: You should try this: `id <- (map["id"], TransformOf<String, Int>(fromJSON: { String($0!) }, toJSON: { $0.map { Int($0) } }))`